# Is there a LaTeX symbol with two arcs like \asymp but with opposite order?

Tags: symbols, arc

`\asymp` creates )( , horizontally. In a programming language semantics work I see a similar thing but with opposite order: (), again horizontally. Is there a standard LaTeX command for this?

Comment: Well, a pair of parentheses with nothing inside.

Comment: Is there a trick to rotate it 90 degrees?

Comment: You have the `\rotatebox{90}{···}` command, from the `rotating`  package. But I have a simpler idea, that I'll test first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose this, obtained with `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{accents} 
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\mysymbol}{\setstackgap{S}{0pt}\stackMath%
\mathrel{\stackon{\smile}{\frown}}} 
\begin{document}

    \[ A\mysymbol B \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since the `\asymp` symbol differs from parentheses, `\smile`, `\smallsmile` and any other symbol in curvature, thickness, etc., here is a version made out of `\asymp` by cutting it with `trimclip` and reassembling it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{trimclip,stackengine}

\newcommand{\sympa}{\mathrel{\stackon[.9 pt]{\clipbox*{0pt {.65\height} {\width} {1.1\height}}{$\asymp$}}%
{\clipbox*{0pt 0pt {\width} {.5\height}}{$\asymp$}}}}

\begin{document}

$P\sympa Q\asymp R$

$P\asymp Q\sympa R$

\end{document}
```